# What is a word that means "to be unaware of responsibility" or "to not realize there is a responsibility to take"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means "to be unaware of responsibility" or "to not realize there is a responsibility to take"?

This is for someone who is a narcissist and doesn't even see/realize her wrongdoings, thus not realizing she needs to take responsibility.

The sentence I was hoping to say would be along the lines of, "She was  _______..."

Answer (score 2):

Like @Anton, "oblivious" also came to mind for me, but I also like:

> *nescient*: lacking knowledge; ignorant; agnostic ([Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nescient))

Or, for a tint of darkness:

> *benighted*:  lacking cultural, moral, or intellectual enlightenment; ignorant ([Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/benighted))

Answer (score 1):

Three words come to mind, all close to your need but perhaps dependent on context.

> *heedless* = If you are heedless of someone or something, you do not take any notice of them
>
> [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heedless)
>
> *oblivious* = not aware of or not noticing something, especially what is happening around you
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblivious/)
>
> *remiss* = not doing a duty carefully or well enough
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remiss)

My favourite is *heedless*. So we might say "*She was heedless of duty, of responsibility, and of the needs of others.*"